# convert an array of arrays to json

Tags: php, arrays, json

i want to convert this array as shown below

```
array_countries=array("20"=>array("cntryValue"=>"3","cntryLabel"=>"Egypt","value"=>"7","label"=>"Tanta"),
"21"=>array("cntryValue"=>"3","cntryLabel"=>"Egypt","value"=>"1000","label"=>"Other"),
"22"=>array("cntryValue"=>"80","cntryLabel"=>"India","value"=>"0","label"=>"All"),
"23"=>array("cntryValue"=>"80","cntryLabel"=>"India","value"=>"1","label"=>"Ahmedabad"));
```

into this format:

```
"3":{"Egypt":{"7":Tanta,"1000":"other"}},"80":{"India":{"0":"All","1":Ahmedabad}}
```

I am using PHP and not able to figure out how can i do this. I have used json_encode. but the results are not correct.I am using PHP as my language.

thanks in advance

Comment: What is your php code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before converting into json, you should change the array:

```
$array_countries_formated = array();

foreach ($array_countries as $item)
{
    $array_countries_formated[$item['cntryValue']][$item['cntryLabel']][$item['value']] = $item['label'];
}

echo $array_countries_formated = json_encode($array_countries_formated, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Result:

```
{"3":{"Egypt":{"7":"Tanta","1000":"Other"}},"80":{"India":{"0":"All","1":"Ahmedabad"}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this...**

```
<?php
$array_countries=array("20"=>array("cntryValue"=>"3","cntryLabel"=>"Egypt","value"=>"7","label"=>"Tanta"),
"21"=>array("cntryValue"=>"3","cntryLabel"=>"Egypt","value"=>"1000","label"=>"Other"),
"22"=>array("cntryValue"=>"80","cntryLabel"=>"India","value"=>"0","label"=>"All"),
"23"=>array("cntryValue"=>"80","cntryLabel"=>"India","value"=>"1","label"=>"Ahmedabad"));

$jsonString = json_encode($array_countries);

print_r($jsonString);
?>
```

**Result:**

```
{"20":{"cntryValue":"3","cntryLabel":"Egypt","value":"7","label":"Tanta"},"21":{"cntryValue":"3","cntryLabel":"Egypt","value":"1000","label":"Other"},"22":{"cntryValue":"80","cntryLabel":"India","value":"0","label":"All"},"23":{"cntryValue":"80","cntryLabel":"India","value":"1","label":"Ahmedabad"}}
```

Comment: this is not the result i wanted

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requested output correctly, the following should do the trick:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array_countries as $country) {
    $cntryValue = $country["cntryValue"];
    if (!array_key_exists($cntryValue, $result)) {
        $result[$cntryValue] = array();
    }
    $result[$cntryValue][$country["cntryLabel"]] = array();
    $result[$cntryValue][$country["cntryLabel"]][$country["value"]] = $country["label"];
}

echo json_encode($result) . "\n";
```

A little explanation: the array provided (`$array_countries`) is formatted differently as compared to your requested output. Therefore, it should be converted. That is what the `foreach` loop does. The formatted result can be converted to json using the `json_encode` function.